SwiftUI hidesBottomBarWhenPushed equivalent
I want to hide the tab bar when I push a new view on a navigation stack. I tried this which works but it's not a smooth animation for the tab. Is there a way to do this that creates the same animation as hidesBottomBarWhenPushed in UIKit?
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Detail View")
                        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                } label: {
                    Text("Navigation Link")
                        .navigationTitle("Home")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
        }
    }
}


Okay, so this can be done, however Apple paradigm suggests you don't. I literally had the exact same thing going on within my app, because I wanted to show a "Notification" screen from the Toolbar. It too was nested inside of a TabView. The way that you can do this is to create some value $hidesTabBar this is set to true, whenever your naviation link is clicked. You can tie the two things together by using a .navigationDestination(isPresented...) with a Binding<Bool> defined that listens to .onChange of the isPresented modifier for the .navigationDestination. You're going to run into a few oddities making that hack work, namely you'll need to pass that binding to every view within your TabView or add it to the .environment.
Now that you have a workable solution, you should be aware of how Apple sees this. If you look at all of their native apps that have a TabView, they ALWAYS use a .sheet, .popover, or a .fullscreenCover with a Done button. This is what users expect to see, and it's what they're used to seeing. In addition, when they're inside of a TabView they always expect to be taken back to where they left off at, if they happen to change tabs for any particular reason. This is a UX concern that you should strongly consider.
